# how to store logout time of user in database for each login using MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and MySQL. My project is about a school management system. In this project I have 3 users. Whenever they login, the login time is stored correctly each time. And when a user logs out , the log out time is stored. The problem is, the last logged out time is also updated to the previous log out times for that particular user. Thank You in advance

My code is:

login.php

```
$sql = $conn->query("Insert into userlog (username) values ('$username')");
```

Log out. php

```
<?php

include("php/dbconnect.php");
ob_start();


mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE userlog SET logoutTime = NOW()  WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'   ");


unset($_SESSION['name']);

unset($_SESSION['uid']);

unset($_SESSION['username']);

echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="login.php"; </script>';


?>
```

I expect ,

```
id username login logout
1    1111   12:10  12:20
2    1111   12:40  12:50
```

But my output is like below,

```
id username login logout
1    1111   12:10  12:50
2    1111   12:40  12:50
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO and congrats on learning a new skill! This comment is not related to your question, but I must give you **vital** information! Your sample code shows a vulnerability. You should learn about **[SQL injections](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** ASAP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you only update the latest login time, so add a condition to your `WHERE` clause to that effect:

```
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE userlog 
                    SET logoutTime = NOW()  
                    WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'
                      AND loginTime = (SELECT maxLoginTime 
                                       FROM (SELECT MAX(loginTime) AS maxLoginTime
                                             FROM userlog 
                                             WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]') u)"
            );
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xhVBJnWaio5WjNT3JuJjAQ/0)

Comment: after using your query logout time is like 0000:00:00 . Its not giving any response

Comment: @K.Kishore sorry about that I forgot to add the subquery layer to resolve the "can't select from table which is being updated error". Please give it another try. Note I've added a demo to show the query working on dbfiddle.

Comment: Thank you ! It's working perfectly . Output is quiet good . But I have one doubt in that query you used  a term 'u'. What is that ?

Comment: @K.Kishore when you use a "derived table", that is a subquery in a `FROM` clause, you have to give the table a name e.g. `(SELECT ... FROM ...) AS name`. The `AS` is optional. In this case I have named the table `u`, it didn't really matter what the name was so I just chose the first letter of the main table's name. For more info, try googling "every derived table must have an alias"

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nick